# Storing/logging/printing all the errors collected by errorcollector

Tags: java, junit, errorcollector

I have been using ErrorCollector Rule for collecting the failed test cases with a code that looks something like this :

```
@Rule
ErrorCollector collector = new ErrorCollector();

Map<X, Y> inputOutputMap = new HashMap<X,Y>();
inputOutputMap.add(new X("Input"), new Y("Output"));

//Mocking service layers and returning expected outputs.

for(Entry<X,Y> entry : inputOutputMap.entrySet()){

     String url = "/do/something"        

     Gson gson = new Gson();
     String json = gson.toJson();

    try{
    this.mockMvc.perform(get(url)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(json)).andExpect(status().isInternalServerError());
    } catch(Exception e) {
        collector.checkThat(e.getMessage, entry.getValue().getMessage());
    } 

}
```

So my problem is after collecting all the errors is there a way I can print all the errors also the way I write the test cases is this a write way - iterating a map and checking for output for respective input?

Comment: To answer your second part ("is this a right way"), my suggestion would be that you add a comment to the `checkThat` that gives information about the `entry` that failed. Otherwise if one in 1000 failed and more than one has the same result message, you won't know which failed.

Comment: In what way do you want to `print` them other than what `JUnit` does by default? The `JUnit` report gives you the information for every failure in the `ErrorCollector`.

Comment: The thing is that I looked into the inner functionality of the ErrorCollector. It basically uses an ArrayList of Throwable and adds an error that is occurring while asserting the expected and the value we get as the response. But there is no way that we can iterate the ArrayList.. its private with no getters. So basically I created my own ErrorCollector with a getter of the errors and then I could be printing them to console or logging it in the file along with some other functionality I required for my project context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could extend `ErrorCollector` and make `verify` public. Then call it and catch the `MultipleFailureException`. From that get the `Throwables` via `getFailures`.

[getFailures](http://junit-team.github.io/junit/javadoc/latest/org/junit/runners/model/MultipleFailureException.html#getFailures())

This is probably better than re-implementing `ErrorCollector` from scratch.